# Fill Form Fields From Previous Page Form Data

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I've a form on my Wordpress home page with only one input filed (phone number) and a continue button. When user adds his phone number and presses the continue button, he redirects to the second page with a complete form. The next page form will also have a phone number field which I want to be filled with the previous page data. I don't know how it possible but I think my question is clear so someone will be really here to help me.

I will look forward to have the soonest response.

My website is http://marle.junaidkhawaja.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save your data in $_SESSION and store on second page render

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['phone']=511111111;
?>
```

OR in client side save variable in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("phone", 511111111);
```

AND YOU WILL ACCESS TO VARIABLE FROM ANY (SAME) PAGE

```
localstorafe.getItem("phone");
```

Comment: I am not so much code savvy. Can you guide me how to do this in my Wordpress?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions

Comment: I saw that page but it is the method for JQuery and on the same page fields refilling. I am still confused how and which code to put in order to fill the second page data from the first page. I want to use plugins for the second page form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Junaid Khawaja as MR. Anri answered you can store your data in $_SESSION retrieve data like

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['phone']=511111111;

// retrieve data
echo $_SESSION['phone'];
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain it in detail how to do that dynamically within my Wordpress? what, how and where to put the codes? I want to use the Contact Form 7 Plugin btw.